# Cannot find type definition file for 'yup'. The file is in the program because: Entry point for implicit type library 'yup'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, yup

```
tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "incremental": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I got this error in my tsconfig.json so due to this error i couldn't run "npm run build" this command when i build my nextjs project.Is anyone know to fixed this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add this line to `tsconfig.json` file inside `compilerOptions` object.

```json
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/yup"]
```

Comment: Please work on improving your answer formatting in the future. See the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page for more information.

Comment: This can also happen if you install the `@types/yup` package. For that package it's no longer maintained and yup has their own types.

Comment: `ERROR in ERROR in undefined(undefined,undefined):
undefined:undefined Cannot find type definition file for 'es'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'es'`

Does not work :(

Answer (score 10):

As Nate Wilkins pointed out in his comment, the error is caused by the `@types/yup` package. This package is deprecated and no longer needed as yup now includes its own types in its package so it can just be removed

Answer (score 0):

when i add this line "typeRoots": ["node_modules/yup"]  inside compilerOptions object my build issue is solved

Comment: Why did you copy the existing answer?